# Simple Xml Parsing error in Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, simple-framework

```
<GetProductsForMachine>
<Products>
    <ProductsForMachine>coffee espresso</ProductsForMachine>
    <ProductsForMachine>coffe1</ProductsForMachine>
    <ProductsForMachine>coffee2</ProductsForMachine>

</Products>
```

What must to be the implementation of Class ProductsForMachine,it's difficult because there isn't elements to get theirs value.

I try with following code but i have errors in the parsing..

```
@Root
public class ProductsForMachine{

    @Attribute(name="ProductsForMachine", required=true)
    public String ProductsForMachine;



    @Element(required=false)
    public int value;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `it's difficult because there aren't elements to get theirs value.` Why? `ProductsForMachine`has values in your XML file. Or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: okay please tell me what must be the class for Parsing it because the class which i write doesen't work in parsing..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution assuming that each `<ProductsForMachine>...</ProductsForMachine>`
 entry can be represented by a String.

```
@Root(name="GetProductsForMachine")
public class GetProductsForMachine
{
    @ElementList(name="Products", entry="ProductsForMachine")
    private ArrayList<String> products; /* 1 */


    // Construtors / Methods

}
```

**Note 1:** For the reason why `ArrayList<String>` is used instead of `List<String>` please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113025/remove-class-attribute/12145092#12145092).

It's possible to rename the class / field since the `name` value of the Annotations is set.

You now can deserialize your XML like this:

```
File f = // your xml file

Serializer ser = new Persister();
GetProductsForMachine products = ser.read(GetProductsForMachine.class, f);
```

Btw. `GetProductsForMachine` requires a closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479601/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-xml-element-from-within-a-soap-response-android/12480785#12480785).  It provides a general approach to parsing simple xml when looking for a specific tag.